# Как сделать скрипт для поля пароля. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, password

Я первокурсник, никогда ранее не изучал программирование, делайте поправку:)
Я пишу сайт HTML, знаю, что выглядит всё криво, но нужна форма регистрации. Вообще моя идея: кликаешь на ссылку, тебя перекидывает на новую страницу с регистрацией. Вроде всё нормально, лишь когда пользователь должен создать пароль — возникают проблемы. Пароль должен иметь не меньше 8 символов, сделано: minlength="8"
Также в нём надо как минимум одну букву заглавную, одну маленькую и одну цифру. Вот только почему-то не выходит у меня сделать проверку. **JavaScript я не знаю от слова совсем;)**
Вот скрипт, будьте добры, помогите!

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
 /*password.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
 }
 password.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
 }*/
 password.onkeyup = function() {
  
  if(password.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
   letter.classList.remove("invalid");
   letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
   letter.classList.remove("valid");
   letter.classList.add("invalid");
   password.validity = false;
  }
  
  if(password.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
   capital.classList.remove("invalid");
   capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
   capital.classList.remove("valid");
   capital.classList.add("invalid");
   password.validity = false;
  }
  
  if(password.value.match(numbers)) {
   number.classList.remove("invalid");
   number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
   number.classList.remove("valid");
   number.classList.add("invalid");
   password.validity = false;
  }
  if(password.value.length >= 8) {
   length.classList.remove("invalid");
   length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
   length.classList.remove("valid");
   length.classList.add("invalid");
   password.validity = false;
  }
 } /*The script is not mine, I found it on Google :)*/
 
/*var inputCustomValidation = new CustomValidation();
 
CustomValidation.prototype.checkValidity = function(input) {

  if (!password.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
 this.validity = false;
  }

  if (!password.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
 this.validity = false;
  }
  
  if(!password.value.match(numbers)) {
   this.validity = false;
  }
};*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JavaScript я не знаю от слова совсем;)

Не знаешь - не используй.

```css
input:valid { border: 1px solid green }
input:invalid { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text name=login required>
  <input type=password name=pass required pattern=(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,} title="Пароль должен быть не короче 8 символов и содержать строчную и заглавную буквы и цифру">
  <button>Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо:) Только не использовать не могу, интересно и учить нужно. А как с помощью JS это сделать не подскажете?

Answer (score 1):

На js:

```js
    function Validation(text) {
            var validate = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}/;
            if (validate.test(text)) {
                letter.classList.remove("invalid");
                letter.classList.add("valid");
            } else {
                letter.classList.remove("valid");
                letter.classList.add("invalid");
                password.validity = false;
            }
    }
```

Пример (По Вашим данным - проверка большой и маленькой буквы - именно латинской):

```js
function Validation(text) {
        var validate = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}/;
        if (validate.test(text)) {
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="<p>Пароль корректен</p>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="<p>Пароль НЕ корректный</p>";
        }
}
```

```html
<form>
<div>
<input type=text name=login required>
<input name=pass id="pass" onkeyup="Validation(this.value)" title="Пароль 8 символов + строчную + заглавную буквы + цифру">
<button>Зарегистрироваться</button>
</div>
<div id="err"></div>
</form>
```

Пример с проверкой любой(русской или латинской) маленькой и большой буквы.

```js
function Validation(text) {
        var validate = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-ZА-ЯЁ])(?=.*[a-zа-яё]).{8,}/;
        if (validate.test(text)) {
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="<p>Пароль корректен</p>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="<p>Пароль НЕ корректный</p>";
        }
}
```

```html
<form>
<div>
<input type=text name=login required>
<input name=pass id="pass" onkeyup="Validation(this.value)" title="Пароль 8 символов + строчную + заглавную буквы + цифру">
<button>Зарегистрироваться</button>
</div>
<div id="err"></div>
</form>
```